# Rails reload chartkick based on form input

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, chartkick

I'm using `chartkick` in a rails 4 app. I currently run this code:

`<%= bar_chart groupArticles(metric, limit) %>` (`groupArticles()` being a custom method to get an array into chartkick. For example `<%= bar_chart groupArticles("views", 5)%>` gives me the top five articles by the `views` metric.

Now the question is this: I want to have a little form where the user can for select a different metric or limit to be passed in (i.e. change it to top 3 or from `views` to `date` or w/e).

I want to reload the chart then (I have URL params to get other stuff on the page so I can't use new url params to achieve this (i think?).

The reason behind that is that I have a table where I use url params to sort it by on the same page. I don't want the user to loose this current sorting if he changes the graph.

Is this possible? How do I build that form?

Answer (score 0):

Right now this feature is not implemented yet (see https://github.com/ankane/chartkick/issues/74).

To show new data in the chart I reload the page. It allows re-initialize chart with new data.

Answer (score 0):

As of  [Dec 4, 2016](https://github.com/ankane/chartkick/issues/74#issuecomment-264756524), You can use a combination of JQuery form submission and Chartkick's built-in functionality to refresh the chart without page reload. First, [point your chart at a custom endpoint](https://github.com/ankane/chartkick#say-goodbye-to-timeouts):

```
<%= bar_chart charts_group_articles_path %>
```

Where `charts_group_articles_path` is something like

```
class ChartsController < ApplicationController
  def group_articles_chart
    groupArticles(params[:metric], params[:limit])
  end
end
```

Then, in `app/assets/javascripts/`, create a little file:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('form').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    data = $(this).serialize();

    Chartkick.eachChart( function(chart) {
      chart.updateData(chart.getDataSource() + '?' + data);
    });

    return false;
  });
});
```

Hope this is of help to future explorers!